# Missing dependency for HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm using a HttpClient in a Java desktop application. I've added *httpclient-4.0.1.jar* and *httpmime-4.0.1.jar* to the build path, but I receive the error 'The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files'. Does anyone know which dependency/jar I'm missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably you are missing httpcore jar.

Answer (score 3):

That class is part of the HttpCore library, here's a link showing it's uses:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/class-use/HttpResponse.html

You'll need to include the jar in your classpath / lib.

Comment: I was indeed missing the httpcore jar, but I can only accept one answer.

Comment: No worries, just glad to provide assistance. :)

Comment: Hyperlink is broken

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll also need:

```
httpcore-4.x.x.jar
```

Comment: I was indeed missing the httpcore jar, but I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://findjar.com/class/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: I was indeed missing the httpcore jar, but I can only accept one answer.