# HttpResponse cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, httpresponse, asynchttpclient

In my previous project i used AsyncHttpClient and lib was android-async-http-1.4.8.jar and everything was fine.But now when i am importing that Project in different eclipse environment it is showing..  **The type org.apache.http.HttpResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files** this error.
Anyone kindly help me with this...???
I have gone through [Missing dependency for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341161/missing-dependency-for-httpclient) but didnt get anything.

Comment: have you add the .jar files and added the file dependency ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem with the help of httpcore 4.4.1.jar file.
I added this jar file to my lib folder and then added to build path and cleaned the project. It is working fine now..
Thanks to all of you for your valuable contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Project, GO to Build Path and Make sure that asynchttpclient.jar is marked. And Then Clean Project. It Should Work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing android-async-http-1.4.8.jar

Follow instructions for importing the third-party library, then adding it using Build Path (which makes it known to Eclipse for compilation purposes). Here is the step-by-step:

1. Right-click libs folder in your project and choose Import -> General -> File System, then Next, Browse in the filesystem to find the library's parent directory (i.e.: where you downloaded it to).
2. Click OK, then click the directory name (not the checkbox) in the left pane, then check the relevant JAR in the right pane. This puts the library into your project (physically).
3. Right-click on your project, choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab, then Add JARs..., navigate to your new JAR in the libs directory and add it.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh, I added android-async-http-1.4.8.jar and did all these steps earlier too, then also the problem has not been resolved..

Comment: @Rajesh..When i am going through client.get(url, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

           public void onSuccess(String response){

           }
           public void onSuccess(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

           }
           public void onFailure(int i, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

           }
       }) ; getting an error that the symbol Header cannot be resolved.Could you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with you, do not use the Android6.0 framework,and I try this instead Android5.0, the problem is solved,hope this answer is not too late.

Answer (score 0):

For API23 I downgrade to android-async-http-1.4.4.jar and import org.apache.http.legacy.jar to avoid error with the deprecated Header class. For me works fine.